# how to pass variable in HTML tag in flutter and load into WebView

Tags: flutter, dart

**I want to pass this name variable in input tag value in flutter dart**

var name = 'tarun';

```
        <tr>
                    <td width="28%" align="right" valign="middle" class="labelfont">AMOUNT: </td>
                  <td width="65%" align="left" valign="middle"><input
                        type="text" name="AMOUNT" class="signuptextfield" value= 'name'  autocomplete="off"/></td>
                    <td width="7%" align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: What about going for value= $name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may reefer to following:

```
var name = 'xyz';
String html = """<tr>
                <td width="28%" align="right" valign="middle" class="labelfont">AMOUNT: </td>
                <td width="65%" align="left" valign="middle"><input
                      type="text" name="NAME" class="signuptextfield" value=$name  autocomplete="off"/></td>
                <td width="7%" align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>""";
```

Answer (score 5):

At first, change html code to String.
And add a variable with '$' in changed html string.

```
var name = 'tarun';
String html = """<tr>
                <td width="28%" align="right" valign="middle" class="labelfont">AMOUNT: </td>
                <td width="65%" align="left" valign="middle"><input
                      type="text" name="AMOUNT" class="signuptextfield" value=$name  autocomplete="off"/></td>
                <td width="7%" align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>""";
```

Comment: This is not working Please check and update me